# Allow only digits in input field using ionic3

Tags: angular, validation, ionic3

I have angular directive to allow only digits in input field. But i try to integrate in ionic3, **event.preventDefault()** not working.

can any one suggest the approach to allow only digits.

```
<ion-input OnlyNumber="true" formControlName="oldpass" type="tel" maxlength="6">
```

Directive:

```
  import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener, Input } from '@angular/core';

    @Directive({
      selector: '[OnlyNumber]'
    })
    export class OnlyNumber {

      constructor(private el: ElementRef) { }

      @Input() OnlyNumber: boolean;

      @HostListener('keydown', ['$event']) onKeyDown(event) {
        let e = <KeyboardEvent> event;
        if (this.OnlyNumber) {
          if ([46, 8, 9, 27, 13].indexOf(e.keyCode) !== -1) {
              return;
            }
            // Ensure that it is a number and stop the keypress
            if ((e.shiftKey || (e.keyCode < 48 || e.keyCode > 57)) && (e.keyCode < 96 || e.keyCode > 105)) {
                e.preventDefault();
                //e.stopPropagation();
                //e.stopImmediatePropagation();
                //return false;
            }
          }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

```
<ion-input formControlName="oldpass" type="text" maxlength="6" pattern="^-?[0-9]*[.]?[0-9]+$">
```

Comment: @pradanya, thanks for sharing your answer. But i want to stop the keyboard press completely. The regular expression is another way of handling errors. That is working fine for me. but i am looking for entirely stop the pressing key(i.e, dot(.), comma(,))

Comment: @vishnu, you need to use input instead od ion-input. Like this: <input type="tel" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="value" maxlength="6">